# accessing the column in pandas in different way

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keyerror

I had a data set that looks like:

```
    Id  Economics      English    History  Literature  
0  56          1            1          2        1                     
1  11          1            0          0        1                    
2   6          0            1          1        0                     
3  43          2            0          1        1                     
4  14          0            1          1        0
```

I created this dataset by reading some csv from file, I could very easily accessed the columns just with df['Economics'], for example. Then I save it into the file with:

```
df.to_csv(file_path, sep='\t')
```

But when I reopen the dataset in other function for work i other purposes, and tried to access the columns in the same way, i.e.

```
df=pd.read_csv(file_path, sep='\t')
print df['Economics']
```

I've got

> KeyError: Economics

I tried multiple encoding while reading, and also verified if it's not a multi-index dataframe, but everything was OK with encoding and index. I found out that there are another method: df.get('Economocs'), that, in this case worked without error. But, then, if I wanted iterated over the columns name, looking for 'Economics', again,I had an KeyError.

So my question: Why it happens? why sometimes I can access column directly with df['column_name'] and sometimes I need to use df.get('column_name'). And how to deal with column.names, in the case if the first method doesn't work?

Comment: Can you provide a self-contained example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: @BrenBarn, what do you mean by self-contained example? I updated the question, if it helps to understand the problem

Comment: I mean provide a piece of code and sample data so that someone else can actually run that code and reproduce your error.  It's hard for anyone to help you from just a description of the problem; you need an actual example that other people can use to replicate the problem.

Comment: @Amanda, please execute the following script and update your question with its output: "... print("before: %s" % df.columns); df.to_csv(...); df=pd.read_csv(...); print("after: %s" % df.columns); "

Comment: @Amanda, also try to use sep='\s+' in  "df=pd.read_csv(file_path, sep='\s+')" instead of "sep='\t'".

Comment: Can you post the output from `df.columns.tolist()`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is some unwanted character in the column name. 
Maybe is something like 'Economics  ' or something else.

`df.get('Economics')` in that case would not give KeyError, instead it would just return nothing.

Try checking the output of `df.columns` and the length of the column name with `len(df.columns[1])` .

Comment: There is no trailing extra caracteres , I verified it

Answer (score 0):

I guess you either have trailing spaces in all/some of your column names or even have just one column like in my test example below:

Test data:

```
Id  Economics     English   History   Literature  
56  1   1   2   1
11  1   0   0   1
6   1   1   0   0
43  2   0   1   1
14  1   1   1   0
```

Test code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='\t')
print(df)
print(df.columns.tolist())
```

Output:

```
  Id  Economics     English   History   Literature
0                                  56  1   1   2   1
1                                  11  1   0   0   1
2                                  6   1   1   0   0
3                                  43  2   0   1   1
4                                  14  1   1   1   0
['Id  Economics     English   History   Literature  ']
```

DataFrame has only one column: `'Id  Economics     English   History   Literature  '`

Lets change `sep='\t'` to `sep='\s+'` in `pd.read_csv()` and execute our test code against the same data set:

```
   Id  Economics  English  History  Literature
0  56          1        1        2           1
1  11          1        0        0           1
2   6          1        1        0           0
3  43          2        0        1           1
4  14          1        1        1           0
['Id', 'Economics', 'English', 'History', 'Literature']
```

Comment: No, it's not the issue with separator, cause when I print df.columns I got the valid list of all columns

Comment: @Amanda, "KeyError" - clearly says that you are trying to access unexisting column. So i don't think I can can help you until you post the output of 'df.columns.tolist()' __after__  your last 'pd.read_csv()' call. Anyway, I wish you good luck!