# Sum specific columns if they exist with dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

**Background**

I have a dataframe with multiple columns. I am trying to sum all the E and B values into a single column

```
t_start         t_end           B1  E1      B2  E2
1/11/2021 0:00  1/11/2021 0:05  0   2.03    0   9.01
1/11/2021 0:00  1/11/2021 0:05  0   2.03    0   9.01
1/11/2021 0:00  1/11/2021 0:05  0   2.03    0   9.01
```

**Problem**

Thing is, the file might have 10+ E and B columns, (B1, B2, B3, etc).

**What I've tried**

I've tried the below, but it errors out if the columns don't exist

```
df['sum_b'] = df['b1'] + df['b2'] + df['b3'] ...
```

I've also tried using a group by solution which I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35746847/sum-values-of-columns-starting-with-the-same-string-in-pandas-dataframe), but it doesn't work either, as it drops off my date columns

```
def left(s, amount):
    return s[:amount]

df.T.groupby([left(s, 1) for s in df.T.index.values]).sum().T)
```

**Help Requested**

If anyone knows how to make a dynamic sum formula which will add b and e columns, it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.filter(regex=pattern)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html), where `pattern` is a regular expression designed to pick out your desired columns by name.

To select columns whose name starts with `B` followed immediately by a digit (thus matching `B1`, `B2`, ..., `B10`, and so on):

```
df.filter(regex='^B\d')
```

To sum the values of all such columns:

```
df['sum_b'] = df.filter(regex='^B\d').sum(axis=1)
df['sum_e'] = df.filter(regex='^E\d').sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: thanks boss, that worked like a charm! much appreciated

Comment: You're very welcome, take care!

Comment: This is certainly very cool, but you have to hard-code the column names.

Comment: True, OP asked about an arbitrary number of columns but specifically starting with B and E. If the letter prefixes are also not known in advance, your answer is the way to go!

Answer (score 2):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'\s*\d+$', '', regex=True)
new_df = pd.concat([df[['t_start', 't_end']], df.T.drop(['t_start', 't_end']).groupby(level=0).sum().T], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
          t_start           t_end    B      E
0  1/11/2021 0:00  1/11/2021 0:05  0.0  11.04
1  1/11/2021 0:00  1/11/2021 0:05  0.0  11.04
2  1/11/2021 0:00  1/11/2021 0:05  0.0  11.04
```